# Add text to SharePoint paging

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, jquery-ui

In Sharepoint allitems.aspx page  it shows 30 on the page – is it possible to have it say the number of pages or number of total files (e.g 1-30 of 67 or page 1 of 3) like that using css or jquery? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code into a script editor web part into list view page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
        var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","").replace("}","");
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listId+"')/ItemCount";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {       
                 var itemCount=data.d.ItemCount;
                 var totaltext = $(".ms-paging").text() + " of " + itemCount;
                 $(".ms-paging").text(totaltext);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
      }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below script in script editor webpart for that particular list view or add it in master page to change it for all the list views.

```
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.Core.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\core.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.debug.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.UI.debug.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.UI.Core.debug.js"/>
/// <reference path="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Web Server Extensions\\14\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\SP.UI.Dialog.debug.js"/>
/// <reference path="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ready, "sp.js");

    function ready() {

        var listID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();

        if (listID != null) {
            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

            var web = context.get_site().get_rootWeb();

            var list = web.get_lists().getById(listID);

            context.load(list);

            context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {

                var count = list.get_itemCount();

                var totaltext = $(".ms-paging").text() + " of " + count.toString();

                $(".ms-paging").text(totaltext);

            }, function (sender, args) { });
        }
    }
});
```